# Yii2 SwiftMailer return-path doesn't set

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I'm using Yii2 SwiftMailer extension.

But i've a problem with `return-path`.
I set address, but email hadn't been received on this address.
It came on sender address.

my config:

```
 $body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
 $body .= '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
 $body .= '<head>';
 $body .= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="' . Yii::$app->charset . '" />';
 $body .= '<title></title>';
 $body .= '</head>';
 $body .= '<body>';
 $body .= 'Test Message';
 $body .= '</body>';
 $body .= '</html>';



Yii::$app->mailer->useTransport('system')->compose()
    ->setFrom(['example@some.com' => 'example.com'])
    ->setReturnPath('bounced@some.com')
    ->addHeader('Reply-To', 'bounced@some.com')
    ->setTo('example2@some.com')
    ->setSubject('TEST MESSAGE')
    ->setHtmlBody($body)
    ->send();
```

I tried to use any other ways, but nothing helped me.

Headers from delivery email

```
`Return-path: <example@some.com>
Envelope-to: example2@some.com
Delivery-date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 17:42:28 +0300
Received: from some.com ([159.203.33.129])
by site.com with esmtps (TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
(Exim 4.84)
(envelope-from <example@some.com>)
id 1buhDH-0002DI-S0
for example2@some.com; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 17:42:27 +0300
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=site.com;     s=dkim;
h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-     Version:To:From:Subject:Date:Message-ID;   bh=TJEj83H/pPguf4pMS+4FcdmBzKkRiY+DeLg2oWD2/iQ=;
b=kA3lrgCRo3Wqr6ky6JVhytV6m/Qx1L3NXFybgPWxyBE5bEqqFGWgOEJQd5O5sppbDnfWB780Hz0FKA8OiiT3IrbzvohHzjRf5SD/IYFz6IaGaN9jwVTojo5jFfBv8t6lv9KprH6MFQEqKJ8bqKNGp3HYIW    lr6DXQAEAAl6CogqY=;
Received: from [178.74.217.102] (helo=[127.0.0.1])
by site.com with esmtpsa (TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
(Exim 4.84_2)
(envelope-from <example@some.com>)
id 1buhDG-0001i4-Su
for example2@some.com; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 10:42:27 -0400
Message-ID: <34cb7242e992226ad1d1f74b821c325f@swift.generated>
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 10:42:25 -0400
Subject: TEST MESSAGE
From: "Example.com" <example@some.com>
To: example2@some.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swiftmailer using setReturnPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094250/swiftmailer-using-setreturnpath)

Comment: @Bizley, nope,
this advice doesn't work for me